# How to disable visualstudio.com stored project's multiple check-out default effect all users?

Tags: checkout, azure-devops

Im doing this from workspace manual for all my project. And my colleague making same. Cant i set defaul somewhere when i'm creating project? or from .visualstudio.com ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If users have Server Workspaces you can configure this via Team Explorer. If you connect to a Team Project and click Settings, then Version Control you should see the options that you are looking for.

This setting affects all users of that team project. You will need to set it for each new team project.